# how to assign different css for templates

Tags: css, meteor

we have two design in the application , the design of landing page and the design of dashboard , leaving meteor load all css , resolves in css conflict , so i'd like to load different css for different templates.
tried loading by  `link(rel="stylesheet", href="landing7/css/theme.css")`
and it works , but the app seems to take half a second to display correct layout , 
at first it displays unstyled page and quickly adds css . that's probably the price to pay when working arround the meteor way of preloading and merging css , i'm wondering if there is a better way to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can’t selectively load different CSS pages for different routes/templates. Have your template start with a wrapper, like `<div class="foo-template">`, and namespace your CSS for that template, e.g. `.foo-template h1 {...}`.